# Is David Mitchell's writing style in "Cloud Atlas" representative of the described time period?

Tags: writing-style

I'm reading David Mitchell's "Cloud Atlas", and the narrative is written in very distinctive style, and the most striking characteristic of it is the use of ampersand (&) instead of "and", in every single instance. A representative quote:

> Disgusted, I retorted that I was a husband & a father! & that I should rather die  than abase my dignity & decency with any of his poxed [word removed for decency].

Similarly, "etc." is styled "&c."

For context, the narrator is a notary from California, and the events take place in mid-XIX century (from various references in the text, a few years after 1838).

Is such pervasive use of ampersand in writing common for the period?

Comment: @coleopterist: Thanks for the edit, don't know what happened there -- it's obviously David Mitchell.

Answer (score 1):

“Pervasive use of ampersand” was common [in the 1600's and 1700's](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%26&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share=) but I think that by the mid-1800's the practice already was an anachronism.  I don't have examples at hand, but have read novels of the 1800's where using numerous ampersands in letters was used to signal that the letter-writer was old-fashioned and antiquated.

A mix of usage is seen in some books printed during the period in question.  For example, in ***A complete guide to spinning & trolling shewing how & where to take pike...*** ([1](http://books.google.com/books?id=SeU-AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22%26%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y37kUOykKsbqigKguoHQBQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAg), 1859) *&* appears in some titles and in some abbreviations like *&c* for *etc*, but in most of the text the word *and* usually is spelled out.  I suggest David Mitchell has exaggerated for effect.